# Is omitting a previous university transcript illegal?

Tags: canada, fraud, state-university

One of my friends did really badly in her first attempt at a university in Canada and subsequently dropped out.

She went to another university in Europe and spent a year there.

She then applied to another Canadian university as a transfer student including the transcript of the European university but omitting her transcript of the first Canadian university that she went to.

She got admitted to the unversity in Canada and is studying there.

We were discussing the consequences of her actions if she were to get caught.

If she were to get caught what would most likely happen?

Get suspended, expelled, arrested, jail/prison?

Would this be a crime?

Would it be still be crime if she is studying something that is not law related like a foreign language?

Answer (score -2):

> If she were to get caught what would most likely happen? Get suspended, expelled, arrested, jail/prison?

Most likely it would be inconsequential. She would not go to prison. And she would not be expelled or disciplined unless the university in Canada has a rule requiring disclosure of any and all university transcripts, which seems very unlikely.

Typically what matters to a university is whether the student is capable of earning a degree. That is regardless of the student's prior deficits from an academic standpoint (instances of student fraud might be handled differently, but still short of leading to imprisonment). By accepting her as a transfer student, the second Canadian university evidently concluded that the credits she earned in Europe satisfy the academic requirements for admission.

Comment: Let's look at the [Common Application](https://www.wcupa.edu/_admissions/SCH_ADM/documents/20-21_CommonApp_first-yearapplication.pdf), which is used for a number of universities in US and Canada. Page 3 says "List all colleges where you have taken coursework". Page 7 requires a declaration that everything is true. With this application itself, it seems like she was committing fraud.

Comment: @user71659 "*Let's look at the Common Application*". Hence the condition "*unless the university [...] has a rule requiring disclosure of any and all university transcripts*" in the first paragraph. My [apparently inaccurate] presumption about the likelihood of that requirement does not change what is stated in the application the OP's friend filled and signed.